# Three.js получение координат

Tags: webgl, three.js, координаты, javascript

У меня есть приложение:
[image]

Как я могу получить массив координат, содержащий координаты всех объектов на plain (он является здесь сеткой)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Очень просто, берешь объекты добавленные на сцену и выводишь

например так:

```
THREE.Vector3.prototype.toString = function(){// для удобного вывода
  return this.x.toFixed()+","+this.y.toFixed()+","+this.z.toFixed();
};

for ( var inx = 0; inx < scene.children.length; inx++ )// для вывода всех координат
  for ( var vtx = 0; vtx < scene.children[inx].geometry.vertices[vtx].length; vtx++ )
    alert( scene.children[inx].geometry.vertices[vtx] );
```

как в массив оформить думаю догадаешься. ;)

Comment: Уже не надо, но все равно спасибо:)